# 1C обратиться к документу-основанию для вывода печатной формы

Tags: 1с

Нужно в печатной форме документа вывести данные из табличной части документа основания. Подскажите, как правильно сделать запрос к данным документа основания для вывода их на печать? 
Написала данный код, но он не работает. Пишет поле товары не найдено (а в док-те основании оно точно есть)

```
Процедура Печать(ТабДок, Ссылка) Экспорт
//{{_КОНСТРУКТОР_ПЕЧАТИ(Печать)
Макет = Документы.ЗаявкаНаДоставку.ПолучитьМакет("Печать");
Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст =
"ВЫБРАТЬ
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.АдресДоставки,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.Водитель,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.ВремяДоставки,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.Грузополучатель,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.Грузчик1,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.Грузчик2,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.Дата,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.ДатаДоставки,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.Номер,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.ПробегКонечный,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.СтатусДоставки,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.ТелефонКонтактногоЛица,
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.ТС
|ИЗ
|    Документ.ЗаявкаНаДоставку КАК ЗаявкаНаДоставку
|   ГДЕ
|   ЗаявкаНаДоставку.Ссылка В (&Ссылка)  ";

Запрос2 = Новый Запрос;
Запрос2.Текст =
"ВЫБРАТЬ
|      РеализацияТоваров1.Товары.(
|       НомерСтроки,
|       НаименованиеТовара,
|       ЕдИзм,
|       Количество,
|       Цена,
|       Сумма
|   )
|ИЗ
|   Документ.РеализацияТоваров1 КАК РеализацияТоваров1
|ГДЕ
|   РеализацияТоваров1.Ссылка  В (&ДокументОснование)";

Запрос.Параметры.Вставить("Ссылка", Ссылка);
Запрос2.Параметры.Вставить("Ссылка", Ссылка);

Выборка = Запрос.Выполнить().Выбрать();
 Выборка2 = Запрос2.Выполнить().Выбрать();

ОбластьЗаголовок = Макет.ПолучитьОбласть("Заголовок");
Шапка = Макет.ПолучитьОбласть("Шапка");
ОбластьТоварыШапка = Макет.ПолучитьОбласть("ТоварыШапка");
ОбластьТовары = Макет.ПолучитьОбласть("Товары");
ТабДок.Очистить();

ВставлятьРазделительСтраниц = Ложь;
Пока Выборка.Следующий() ИЛИ Выборка2.Следующий() Цикл
    Если ВставлятьРазделительСтраниц Тогда
        ТабДок.ВывестиГоризонтальныйРазделительСтраниц();
    КонецЕсли;

    ТабДок.Вывести(ОбластьЗаголовок);
    Шапка.Параметры.Заполнить(Выборка);
    ТабДок.Вывести(Шапка, Выборка.Уровень());
    ТабДок.Вывести(ОбластьТоварыШапка);
    ВыборкаТовары = Выборка2.Товары.Выбрать();
    Пока ВыборкаТовары.Следующий() Цикл
        ОбластьТовары.Параметры.Заполнить(ВыборкаТовары);
        ТабДок.Вывести(ОбластьТовары, ВыборкаТовары.Уровень());
    КонецЦикла;


    ВставлятьРазделительСтраниц = Истина;
КонецЦикла;
    //}}
КонецПроцедуры
```

Comment: Мне кажется в коде явно нарушена логика. Сложно сказать, не видя весь код. Например, что содержится в переменной "Выборка" и где определяется переменная "Ссылка"...

Comment: @ Ella Svetlaya поместила весь код. В запросе 2 пытаюсь получить данные из документа основания. Вообще ничего не выводит, выдает ошибку

Comment: Опишите какая конфигурация используется, где в каком реквизите хранится документ основания, какой документ является первичным. Второй запрос у вас неверный - должен быть таким ВЫБРАТЬ * 
|ИЗ
|   Документ.РеализацияТоваров1.Товары КАК РеализацияТоваров1
|ГДЕ
|   РеализацияТоваров1.Ссылка  = &ДокументОснование

Comment: @ivansoft Всего вторую неделю пытаюсь разобраться в 1с с нуля, так что извините за глупые вопросы. Я думала, что когда документ создаем на основании другого, в нем автоматом должна появляться ссылка на док.основание. Это не так?Я должна создать реквизит, где прописать ссылку на док.основание?

Comment: @ivansoft внесла изменение в код, как вы написали. Выдает ошибку: "{Документ.ЗаявкаНаДоставку.МодульМенеджера(46)}: Ошибка при вызове метода контекста (Выполнить)
  Выборка2 = Запрос2.Выполнить().Выбрать();
по причине:
{(13, 28)}: Не задано значение параметра "ДокументОснование"
РеализацияТоваров1.Ссылка=<<?>>&ДокументОснование"

Comment: первичный документ РеализацияТоваров1, на его основании создаю Заявку на доставку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько замечаний по коду:

1. ЗаявкаНаДоставку.Ссылка В (&Ссылка) - бессмысленно использовать В, если в параметре - один документ. ЗаявкаНаДоставку.Ссылка = &Ссылка.
2. Во втором запросе нет параметра Ссылка, а он зачем-то устанавливается. Зато не устанавливается нужный параметр ДокументОснование.
3. Старайтесь все данные, которые нужно получить, получать в одном запросе. Если у Вас совсем разные данные в запросах - делайте несколько, но в пакетном запросе. Это повышает быстродействие за счёт уменьшения количества обращений к базе данных.
4. Ответ на ваш комментарий - да, чтобы документ-основание был у другого документа, нужно создать реквизит в этом документе и вам нужно самостоятельно в коде позаботиться о том, чтобы этот реквизит заполнялся.
5. Без полного описания того, что вы хотите, сложно вам помочь. Какие данные должны получаться из документа, а какие - из его основания? Какая между ними взаимосвязь? Общая схема запроса примерно отвечающего вашим условиям:

`ВЫБРАТЬ
    ВозвратДенег.Ссылка КАК ДокументВозвратДенег,
    ВозвратДенег.Валюта КАК Валюта,
    ВозвратДенег.Контрагент КАК Контрагент,
    ВозвратДенег.Дата,
    ДенежныеРасходыРасходы.СтатьяРасходов,
    ДенежныеРасходыРасходы.Сумма,
    ДенежныеРасходыРасходы.Ссылка КАК ДокументДенежныеРасходы
ИЗ
    Документ.ВозвратДенег КАК ВозвратДенег
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Документ.ДенежныеРасходы.Расходы КАК ДенежныеРасходыРасходы
        ПО ВозвратДенег.ДокументОснование = ДенежныеРасходыРасходы.Ссылка
ИТОГИ
    МАКСИМУМ(Валюта),
    МАКСИМУМ(Контрагент)
ПО
    ДокументВозвратДенег`

Пояснения - **ВозвратДенег** здесь - это документ, а **ДенежныеРасходы** - это основание. Ссылка на основание хранится в реквизите **ДокументОснование** - вы видите это в условии связи. Итоги здесь для того, чтобы получить двухуровневое дерево - на верхнем уровне будет документ **ВозвратДенег** и его реквизиты. Обратите внимание - все его реквизиты указаны в разделе **ИТОГИ**. Это для того, чтобы они выводились на верхнем уровне. Остальные реквизиты - реквизиты документа-основания, будут находиться на втором уровне дерева. Обход делается так:

```
РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();

ВыборкаДокументВозвратДенег = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать(ОбходРезультатаЗапроса.ПоГруппировкам);

Пока ВыборкаДокументВозвратДенег.Следующий() Цикл
    // Вставить обработку выборки ВыборкаДокументВозвратДенег

    ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи = ВыборкаДокументВозвратДенег.Выбрать();

    Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл
        // Вставить обработку выборки ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи
    КонецЦикла;
КонецЦикла;
```

Comment: извините, только сейчас посмотрела, давненько тут не была.